# Passing a Callable as parameter to a method and use its return value as parameter for that same method

Tags: java, selenium

I have written a method that takes in a Callable and an array of arbitrary length of Strings that I use to time the execution time of the Callable and then write the results to a database:

```
public static <T> T logTimes(Callable<T> callable, String actionToTest, String... testData) throws Exception {
        LocalDateTime before = null;
        T call = null;
        try {
            before = LocalDateTime.now();
            call = callable.call();
            logToDocument(before, LocalDateTime.now(), actionToTest, testData);
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            logToDocument(before, LocalDateTime.now(), actionToTest, testData);
        }
        return call;
    }
```

This works fine, but I have now run into a situation where I need to pass the return value of the Callable as a parameter to the same method:

```
public static String loadedPageName(WebDriver driver, int seconds) throws Exception {
        String originPage = pageName(driver);
        By loadingBar = By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'progress')]");
        WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
        Function<WebDriver, Boolean> pageFinishedLoading = wd -> wd.findElements(loadingBar).size() == 0;
        AtomicReference<String> dest = new AtomicReference<>();
        try {
            return ExtentTestManager.logTimes(()-> {
                w.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(loadingBar));
                w.until(pageFinishedLoading);
                dest.set(driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getAttribute("page-name"));
                return dest;
            }, REDIRECT, ORIGIN, originPage, DESTINATION, dest.get()).get();
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            ExtentTestManager.reporterLog("Timeout after waiting ".concat(String.valueOf(seconds)).concat(" seconds for a page to load"));
            ExtentTestManager.logToDocument(LocalDateTime.now(), seconds, REDIRECT, ORIGIN, originPage, DESTINATION, "timeout");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This method waits until a page has loaded and returns the name of the loaded page. I want to use that return value as a parameter in the same invocation of `ExtentTestManager.logTimes(Callable<T> callable, String actionToTest, String... testData)` as the `Callable<T> callable` that is one of its parameters.

As it is now, `loadedPageName(WebDriver driver, int seconds)` returns the page name as expected, but `logTimes` writes `null` to the database for the result of `callable`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in logTimes is equivalent to:

```
    try {
        before = LocalDateTime.now();
        call = callable.call();
        
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        // do nothing with the exception
    }
    logToDocument(before, LocalDateTime.now(), actionToTest, testData);
```

Maybe you want to do something with the TimeoutException?
Also the calling code in loadedPageName will never encounter a TimeoutException since it is already caught (and ignored) in logTimes.

Regarding your question, there is a problem with the last testData value: `dest.get()`. This will not be filled with a value yet when it is evaluated (which is before the logTimes method is executed). Probably that's your issue: you are passing the value of the empty AtomicReference in as testData for logTimes to display.

You are passing in testData Strings before your Callable is executed, so the result of the Callable can never be part of this testData. If you need the result of the callable you could edit the logTimes method to always use the result of the callable as the first/last testData for instance:

```
public static <T> T logTimes(Callable<T> callable, String actionToTest, String... testData) throws Exception {
    LocalDateTime before = LocalDateTime.now();
    T call = callable.call();
    List<String> allTestData = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(testData));
    allTestData.add(String.valueOf(call));
    logToDocument(before, LocalDateTime.now(), actionToTest, allTestData.toArray(new String[0]));        
    return call;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the redundant TimeOutException. Regarding the empty AtomicReference, is there a way to fill that AtomicReference, or would I be better off refactoring my code?

Comment: The problem is your are passing in testData Strings before your Callable is executed, so the result of the Callable can never be testData. If you need the result of the callable you could edit the logTimes method to always use the result of the callable as the first/last testData for instance